# Sums of digits 1 through 7

Tags: code-golf, math, number

## Challenge

Given a positive integer `N` that is 28 or above, output a list of numbers summing to `N` that uses each digit `1` through `7` exactly once. You can give as a program or function.

The digits can appear by themselves or concatenated, as long as you use each of them once without repeats. For example,`[12, 34, 56, 7]` is valid, as is `[1, 27, 6, 4, 35]` and `[1234, 567]`, but not `[123, 34567]` or `[3, 2, 1476]`. The order that the numbers are listed does not matter.

If `N` cannot be made with 1-7, return or output nothing.

## Other information

- This is code golf, so the shortest code in bytes by Thursday the 15th of October wins.
- Ask any questions in the comments.
- Anything I do not specify in the challenge is up to you.
- Standard loopholes are disallowed.

## Examples

These may clear any confusion up:

Input

```
28
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Input

```
100
```

Output

```
[56, 7, 4, 31, 2]
```

Input

```
1234567
```

Output

```
[1234567]
```

Input

```
29
```

Output

Nothing, 29 is invalid.

Input

```
1891
```

Output

```
[1234, 657]
```

Input

```
370
```

Output

```
[15, 342, 7, 6]
```

I'll make more if needed.

[Here's](http://pastebin.com/qBUGp9RG) a pastebin of all of the possible numbers created with these seven numbers, courtesy of FryAmTheEggman.

Comment: What's the output for `29`?

Comment: @Geobits That's impossible, so nothing.

Comment: If you want the output to be nothing, don't put `(N/A)` as the output.

Comment: @mbomb007 Fixed.

Comment: why would 1234567 result in [1234567] ? You can have less than 7 numbers like f.e. [1234566, 1] ?

Comment: @LukStorms The object is to use each digit 1-7 exactly once.

Comment: @LukStorms `[1234566, 1]` is not a valid output, because 6 is repeated. You may not repeat numbers in the output.

Comment: Ok, I'm guessing most solutions will have to resort to a brute force method for this one.

Comment: Maybe »... a list of numbers made from the decimal digits 1 to 7 which sum up to N« is a clearer wording than the one currently in the question.

Comment: For a slightly less brute force solution: This is equivalent to assigning a power-of-10 coefficient to each of `1, ..,, 7` so that there's at least as many `1`'s as `10`'s, at least as many `10`'s as `100`'s, and so on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>18</s> 14 bytes

```
hfqSjkTjkS7./Q
```

*Thanks to @isaacg for golfing off 2 bytes and paving the way for 2 more.*

The code will crash if it should produce no output, which causes no output to be produced.

This will work for small-ish inputs if you're patient enough, and for larger ones if given enough time and memory.

To verify that the code works as intended, you can replace the `7` with a `3` for *sums of digits 1 through 3*. Click [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=hfqSjkTjkS3.%2FQ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=6%0A15%0A7) for a test suite.

#### Example runs

```
$ time pyth/pyth.py -c 'hfqSjkTjkS7./Q' <<< 28
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

real    4m34.634s
user    4m34.751s
sys     0m0.101s
$ time pyth/pyth.py -c 'hfqSjkTjkS7./Q' <<< 29 2>/dev/null

real    9m5.819s
user    9m6.069s
sys     0m0.093s
```

#### How it works

```
           ./Q    Compute all integer partitions of the input.
 f                Filter the integer partitions:
    jkT             Join the integers with empty separator.
   S                Sort the characters of the resulting string.
      jkS7          Join [1, ..., 7] with empty separator.
  q                 Check both results for equality.
                  Keep the partition of `q' returned True.
h                 Retrieve the first element of the filtered list.
                  For a non-empty list, this retrieves the solution.
                  For the empty list, it causes an error and produces no output.
```

Comment: Well done! Quite an innovative approach. ```MS7`` is shorter than `r\1\8`. Also `@ .. 0` is the same as `h`.

Comment: @isaacg Thanks! I'm not sure how I missed `h`, but I had no idea you could use `S` that way. (The char reference in the online interpreter doesn't mention it.) `jkS7` seems to be even shorter, since I don't need `s` anymore.

Answer (score 5):

### Python 3, 109

```python
def f(n,s=set('1234567'),l='0,'):[f(n,s-{x},l+x+c)for c in(',','')for x in s]or n-sum(eval(l))or~print(l[2:])
```

A function that takes a number and outputs a tuple in the like `123,4567,`. Yes, this is a valid tuple.

The idea is to generate all possible strings like `43,126,7,5,` that have the digits `1` through `7` separated by commas, with no two commas consecutive. Evaluate this expression as a tuple, and its sum equals `n`, print it and terminate with error.

To build all such strings, we track the set `s` of chars to use, and try appenping each one either with a comma, which makes the digit end the entry, or without, in which case future digits will concatenate onto it.

Short-circuiting is used to check that `s` is empty because the list-comp is empty, and that `n==sum(eval(l))`, in which case we print `l` and terminate with an error by taking `~` of the `None` returned by printing (thanks to Sp3000 for this.).

I believe that in Python 3.5, two chars can be saved by writing `s={*'1234567'}` (thanks Sp3000).

There's some small annoyances that eat up chars. One is that in the case that `l` looking like `1234567` with no commas, it is parsed as a single number and calling `sum` gives an error. This is handled with the hack of starting `l` with the element `0` and stripping it when printing. This costs 6 chars.

Iterating `c` over the comma and the empty string is annoyingly wordy `for c in(',','')`, since Python 3 doesn't allow this tuple to be naked. I'd like there to be some char `?` that is ignored in numbers to do `',?'` for 4 chars less, but there doesn't seem to be such a char.

---

Old method:

**Python 2, 117**

```python
def f(n,s={1,2,3,4,5,6,7},l=[],p=0):
 if{n,p}|s=={0}:print l;1/0
 if p:f(n-p,s,l+[p])
 for x in s:f(n,s-{x},l,p*10+x)
```

Defines a function that takes a number and prints a list.

The idea is to use recursion to try every branch. The variables track are

- The remaining sum `n` needed
- The set of digits `s` remaining to use
- The list `l` of numbers made so far
- The current partially-formed number `p`

When `n==0` and `s` is empty, print `l` and terminate by error.

If the current partially-formed number `p` is non-zero, try adding it to the list and removing it from the remaining sum.

For each digit `x` we can use from `s`, try appending it to `p` and removing it from `s`.

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 23

```
#iRThfqQsiR10Ts./M.pS7q
```

Naive brute force, too slow online, takes about a minute on my computer. Uses the common "loop forever until exception" pattern of pyth golfs where accessing the resulted filtered list of combinations causes an error for impossible numbers, like `29`.

Outputs like a pythonic list, e.g.

```
1891
[1234, 657]
100
[1, 2, 34, 56, 7]
370
[12, 345, 6, 7]
```

Here is a [paste](http://pastebin.com/qBUGp9RG) of all of the 10136 numbers that can be made this way.

Comment: May I use the pastebin link for examples?

Comment: @The_Basset_Hound Of course, go ahead.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 165 <s>196</s>

**Edit** Shortened a little. Could be shorter using `eval`, but I like it being fast

Brute force, shamefully longer than Pith version, but faster. Test running the snippet below in an EcmaScript 6 compliant browser.

```js
f=z=>{for(r=i=1e6;r&&++i<8e6;)for(m=/(.).*\1|[089]/.test(w=i+'')?0:64;r&&m--;t.split`+`.map(v=>r-=v,r=z))for(t=w[j=0],l=1;d=w[++j];l+=l)t+=l&m?'+'+d:d;return r?'':t}

function test() { O.innerHTML=f(+I.value) }

test()

// Less golfed

f=z=>{
  for(r=i=1e6; r&&++i<8e6;)
    for(m=/(.).*\1|[089]/.test(w=i+'')?0:64; r&&m--; t.split`+`.map(v=>r-=v,r=z))
      for(t=w[j=0],l=1;d=w[++j];l+=l)
        t+=l&m?'+'+d:d;
  return r?'':t
}
```

```html
<input id=I value=28><button onclick=test()>-></button><span id=O></span>
```

Comment: No shame to be longer because of language, I really enjoy your JS answers, +1

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2.7, <s>178</s> <s>172</s> 169 bytes

```
n=input()
for i in range(8**7):
 for j in len(set('%o0'%i))/8*range(128):
    s=''
    for c in'%o'%i:s+='+'[:j%2*len(s)]+c;j/=2
    if eval(s)==n:print map(int,s.split('+'));1/0
```

Note that the last three lines are supposed to be indented with tabs but I
can't figure out how to do so in this editor.

Edit: Flattened one layer of nesting with the help of Sp3000

Comment: SE strips out tabs unfortunately, so just saying how it's meant to be indented is fine :)

Comment: Ah okay, still figuring my way around this site.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <s>270</s> 268 bytes

```
from itertools import*;P=permutations
x,d,f=range(1,8),[],input()
r=sum([[int(''.join(str(n)for n in i))for i in list(P(x,j))]for j in x],[])
z=1
while z:
 t=sum([[list(j)for j in P(r,z)]for i in x],[])
 v=filter(lambda i:sum(i)==f,t)
 if v:print v[0];break
 else:z+=1
```

Still working on golfing.

This loops until a match is found.

Comment: `import as` is rarely necessary - you can do `from itertools import*;P=permutations`

Comment: It's shorter to use `map(str,i)` than the list comprehension, and you can construct the list r directly rather than by flattening a nested list: `r=[int(''.join(map(str,i)))for j in x for i in P(x,j)]`, and a similar thing for t.

Comment: You can use `\`n\`` instead of `str(n)`, since `n` will never be above the maximum integer.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell (145 bytes)

```
main=getLine>>=print.head.f[1..7].read
f[]0=[[]]
f b s=[n:j|(n,g)<-m b,j<-f g$s-n]
m b=[(d+10*z,g)|d<-b,(z,g)<-(0,filter(/=d)b):m(filter(/=d)b)]
```

Uses recursion.

Ungolfed (337 bytes):

```
delete d = filter (/= d)
main = getLine >>= print . (`form` [1..7]) . read

form s [] | s == 0    = [[]]
form s ds | s <= 0    = []
form s ds | otherwise = [n:ns | (n, ds') <- makeNumbers ds, ns <- form (s-n) ds']

makeNumbers [] = []
makeNumbers ds  = [(d + 10 * n',ds') | d <- ds, (n',ds') <- (0,delete d ds):makeNumbers (delete d ds)]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
ŒṗDẎṢ⁼ʋƇ7R¤Ḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9qZWxsef//xZLhuZdE4bqO4bmi4oG8yovGhzdSwqThuKL///8yOA)

Times out for pretty much all inputs. Outputs `0` if no such list exists. Requiring empty output adds [3 bytes](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9qZWxsef//xZLhuZdE4bqO4bmi4oG8yovGhzdSwqThuKJv4oCc4oCd////Mjk).

[This](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f9qZWxsef//N8WSIcWS4bmW4oKs4bqO4biMUz3CpcaH4oG44bii////Mjk) is a 14 byte ([17 for empty output](https://tio.run/##ATEAzv9qZWxsef//N8WSIcWS4bmW4oKs4bqO4biMUz3CpcaH4oG44biib@KAnOKAnf///zI5)) answer which has a more or less constant runtime (~40 seconds).

### How they work

```
ŒṗDẎṢ⁼ʋƇ7R¤Ḣ - Main link. Takes n on the left
Œṗ           - Integer partitions of n
      ʋƇ     - Keep those for which the following is true:
  D          -   Convert to digits
   Ẏ         -   Flatten
    Ṣ        -   Sorted
     ⁼  7R¤  -   Equals [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
           Ḣ - Take the first list
```

The 14 byte version:

```
7Œ!ŒṖ€ẎḌS=¥Ƈ⁸Ḣ - Main link. Takes n on the left
7              - Yield 7
 Œ!            - Get all permutations of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
     €         - Over each:
   ŒṖ          - Yield it's partitions
      Ẏ        - Flatten to a single list of all partitions
       Ḍ       - Convert from digits
          ¥Ƈ   - Keep those for which the following is true:
        S      -   Sum
         =  ⁸  -   Equals n
             Ḣ - Take the first list
```

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 195 bytes

This isn't the most efficient and it took over 15 minutes to get the output for 29 but it works

```
def g(s: Seq[Int]): Iterator[Seq[Int]]=s.combinations(2).map(c=>g(c.mkString.toInt +: s.filterNot(c.contains))).flatten ++ Seq(s)
def f(i: Int)=(1 to 7).permutations.map(g).flatten.find(_.sum==i)
```

Here is some output

```
scala> f(100)
res2: Option[Seq[Int]] = Some(Vector(46, 35, 12, 7))

scala> f(1891)
res3: Option[Seq[Int]] = Some(Vector(567, 1324))

scala> f(370)
res4: Option[Seq[Int]] = Some(Vector(345, 12, 6, 7))

scala> f(29)
res5: Option[Seq[Int]] = None
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 105 bytes

Brute force! Checks every subset of lengths between 0 and 7 of the integers between 1 and 7654321 and sees if any of them matches our criteria. You probably don't want to wait for this to terminate.

```ruby
->n{8.times{|i|[*1..7654321].permutation(i){|x|return x if
x.join.chars.sort==[*?1..?7]&&eval(x*?+)==n}}}
```

To run and verify the algorithm you can narrow down the search space by replacing `7654321` with the largest number you know will be in the answer. For instance, 56 for n=100, or 1234 for n=1891. Here's a trial run of the latter:

```
$ ruby -e "p ->n{8.times{|i|[*1..1234].permutation(i){|x|return x if x.join.chars.sort==[*?1..?7]&&eval(x*?+)==n}}}[gets.to_i]" <<< 1891
[657, 1234]
```

Comment: 0 to 7 integers? You should use exaclty 7 integers: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

Comment: @edc65 You mean exactly 7 *digits*. The result is a set of integers, and the size of the set depends on the input.

Comment: I don't speak Ruby, I presume the program works, but I don't get the explanation. If your integers are less than 1234567, how do you get 7654321?

Comment: @edc65 You're right, I'll have to change that number. I'll try to explain it better too.

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 15 bytes

```
ḟȯ=ḣ7Oṁdfo=¹ΣṖḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@GO@SfW2z7csdjc/@HOxpS0fNtDO88tfrhzGlDo////hgYGAA)